# Finding the exclusive records in a table

Tags: sql, mysql

I am a beginner at SQL. I have a single table called enrolment where I have users (user_id) who can have either single or multiple courses which are represented using course_id.

I want to find the users who are only enrolled into the course 10, have no due fees (due_fee) and nothing else.
This is my attempt at this problem but it is not working:

`SELECT user_id FROM student_enrollment WHERE course_id = 10 and due_fee = 0.00`

This query is selecting the users who have a course_id of 10 but how do I filter this so that the users who have both 10 and other course_id's are removed? Then the end result would only be the users with course_id 10.

Comment: Incredible quality answers for your first question, good job! haha

Comment: Yes, very helpful answers posted here. Finally solved my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could phrase this using exists logic:

```sql
SELECT user_id
FROM student_enrollment se1
WHERE course_id = 10 AND due_fee = 0 AND
      NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM student_enrollment se2
          WHERE se2.user_id = se1.user_id AND
                se2.course_id <> 10
      );
```

Another approach, using aggregation:

```sql
SELECT user_id
FROM student_enrollment
WHERE due_fee = 0
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(course_id <> 10) = 0;
```

Comment: That feeling when you are testing a solution and a 500k user pitches in haha

Comment: Thanks for answering. How can I modify the the HAVING clause condition to match the edited question?
I want to include another column where the user's due_fee = 0. I tried putting this in the where clause but its giving me incorrect results.

Comment: Does it matter than another user does/does not also have a zero due_fee?

Comment: Yes, so I am trying to get all the users who are exclusively enrolled in course_id = 10 and then filter the people who paid the fees (due_fee).

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to use `EXCEPT`: Find all users that take a class #10 without due fee except those who also take another class.

```
SELECT user_id FROM student_enrollment WHERE course_id = 10 and due_fee = 0
EXCEPT
SELECT user_id FROM student_enrollment WHERE course_id <> 10
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/except.html

Comment: Thank you for answering but MySQL Workbench is giving me an error: "EXCEPT is not valid at this position". Any suggestions regarding this please?

Comment: It seems your MySQL version is too old. In the link they say `EXCEPT` was added in MySQL 8.0.31 (release date: October 11, 2022). Or you have a typo. Or there is a bug in your MySQL version.

Answer (score 2):

Using conditional aggregation and filter:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM
(
SELECT user_id, 
       count(case when course_id = 10 then 1 else 0 end) cnt_10,
       count(case when course_id <> 10 then 1 else 0 end) cnt_other
  FROM student_enrollment s
 GROUP BY user_id
) s
WHERE cnt_10>0 and cnt_other=0
```

OR

```
SELECT user_id
  FROM student_enrollment s
 GROUP BY user_id
HAVING count(case when course_id = 10 then 1 else 0 end)>0
   AND count(case when course_id <> 10 then 1 else 0 end)=0
```

Comment: You don't need a subquery...you could just put the counting assertion in the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen True.